# Node JS Leaflet tile serving from same domain error

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, leaflet, tiles

I have been using the script at: http://leaflet-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/build/master/leaflet.js
running this web application to overlay tilelayers: http://www.wherewillplantsgrow.com/

Since 2 days ago, an issue has started where tiles start getting called where they weren't called before causing slow tiles serving and tiles images not found errors.

The map js code gist is here: 
https://gist.github.com/abdelhas/40cd9d1ed932578bb6cf

My question is has anyone encountered this issue before? is there a problem with my script (i haven't touched it for a week now) or with the leaflet script above (possibly after an update).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `http://leaflet-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/build/master/leaflet.js`: the version behind that script will change. Use a **versioned** URL: see the ['Use a Hosted Version' of Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/download.html) part of this page

Comment: Thanks! I found it was because an update affected that file. Refer to: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3013#issuecomment-62529558